# Why exactly did you choose MAVEN for your selenium project

Tags: java, maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I was wondering what could be the good answer to "Why was the need to use Maven and Not Jenkins or other framework"
This is with respect to an automation project created in selenium and testNG with Maven framework

Comment: Jenkins is a CI platform. Maven is a build tool. They're just not the same thing, and don't have the same purpose. You use Maven because you need to build, and you prefer it over other build tools, that's pretty much it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of fundamental and functional difference between the usability of [**`Maven`**](https://maven.apache.org/#) and [**`Jenkins`**](https://jenkins-ci.org/)

---

### Maven :

**`Apache Maven`** popularly known as **`Maven`** is a **`Software Project Management`** tool. Based on the concept of a **`Project Object Model (POM)`**, Maven can manage a project's build, reporting and documentation from a central piece of information dynamically which is configured through a file **`pom.xml`**.

From **`Selenium Framework`** perspective, **`Maven`** enables you to to get rid of the manual configuration of **`Selenium JARS`** and **`WebDrivers`**. You can easily switch over from one version of the underlying software to another through a simple update in **`pom.xml`**.

---

### Jenkins :

**`Jenkins`** is a popular tool for **`Continous Integration (CI)`** which can be used as a simple CI server or turned into the continuous delivery hub for any project. Jenkins being a self-contained `Java-based Program` is always ready to run out-of-the-box with packages for **`Windows`**, **`Mac OSX`** and other **`Unix`**-like operating systems. Jenkins can be easily configured through its web interface to integrate **`on-the-fly check-ins`** and **`built-in`** help.

From **`Selenium Test Automation`**  perspective, through **`Jenkins`** you would be able to schedule the **`Test Execution`** whenever you require and as many times you may require.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. I have got it now!!